# How can I split a list of strings into a new list where the string values are smaller

Tags: python, list, split

I want to take a list such as
`POINTS = ['97571,97572,97573,97847,97848,97849,97850,98123,98124,98125,98126,98127']`
and make it into multiple smaller lists.

```
Points1 = ['97571,97572,97573']
Points2 = ['97847,97848,97849']
Points3 = ['97850,98123,98124']
Points4 = ['98125,98126,98127']
```

and then back into a single list

`POINTS1 = ['97571,97572,97573','97847,97848,97849','97850,98123,98124','98125,98126,98127']`

I had tried this:

```
def split(arr, size):
    arrs = []
    while len(arr) > size:
        pice = arr[:size]
        arrs.append(pice)
        arr = arr[size:]
    arrs.append(arr)
    return arrs
```

```
def redefine():
    int_list = ["0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"]
    newww = [i.split(",") for i in int_list]
    temp_list = newww[0]new_temp_list = []
    for m in range(10):
        x = int(temp_list[m])
```

```
        new_temp_list.append(x)
        print(new_temp_list)

    f =split(new_temp_list,5)
    print("This is f: " + str(f))
    y = "".join(str(f))
    print("This is y: " + y)
    yy = y.replace("[","'").replace("]","'")
    print("This is yy: " +yy)
```

However, I am stuck trying to format the new lists into the proper form. I'm sure there is a simpler way.

Comment: "and make it into multiple smaller lists." - **what is the rule that tells you** how to split it? How many lists should there be as a result? Where are the splits allowed to be?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

```py
POINTS = ['97571,97572,97573,97847,97848,97849,97850,98123,98124,98125,98126,98127']

n = 3
vals = POINTS[0].split(',')

POINTS1 = [','.join(v) for v in zip(*(vals[i::n] for i in range(n)))]
print(POINTS1)
```

Prints:

```
[
 '97571,97572,97573', 
 '97847,97848,97849', 
 '97850,98123,98124', 
 '98125,98126,98127'
]
```

Comment: Wow, yes, thank you! I think this is exactly what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Please read [answer] and don't try to read OP's mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator from the comma-splitted list and use `itertools.islice` on it to generate chunks of a fixed size:

```
from itertools import islice

POINTS = ['97571,97572,97573,97847,97848,97849,97850,98123,98124,98125,98126,98127']
chunk_size = 3

seq = iter(POINTS[0].split(','))
POINTS1 = []
while chunk := ','.join(islice(seq, chunk_size)):
    POINTS1.append(chunk)
```

or use the 2-argument `iter` function to keep slicing until an empty string is met:

```
from itertools import islice

POINTS = ['97571,97572,97573,97847,97848,97849,97850,98123,98124,98125,98126,98127']
chunk_size = 3

POINTS1 = list(iter(
    lambda seq=iter(POINTS[0].split(',')): ','.join(islice(seq, chunk_size)), ''))
```

In both codes `POINTS1` would become:

```
['97571,97572,97573', '97847,97848,97849', '97850,98123,98124', '98125,98126,98127']
```